# select values from 2 forms in 2 php pages and get output result to 3rd php page

Tags: php

I have 3 pages in php. Page 1 includes a search form where the user enters a name wants to search in my database:

```
<form method="get[value]" name="go" action="search_form_all.php"  >
    <input name="value" type="text" id="search_form_1" size="65"  autocomplete="off" placeholder=" Search People ..." />
    <input type="submit" value="" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Page 2 includes a php script that gets the value that user enters in search form (of page 1) and returns all names from my database with success.

```
$value = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['value']);

$name_and_surname = explode(" ", "$value ");
$name = $name_and_surname[0];
$surname = $name_and_surname[1]; 

$sql = " SELECT `name`, `surname`, `email`, `user_id` FROM users WHERE (surname LIKE '$name%' AND name LIKE '$surname%') OR (surname LIKE '$surname%' AND name LIKE '$name%') ";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($run = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  $surname = $run['surname'];
  $name = $run['name'];

echo"<a href='profile_full.php?email=$email'>  $surname  $name  </a>"; 
}
//page until now prints all names that user enters in search form.

//In order to give user the option to display all names that are from a certain country, bellow I use this code:

<form method="get[value]" name="go" action="location.php"  >        
    <select name="country"> 
    <option value=" "> select </option> 
    <option value="Afganistan">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
    </select>
<input type="submit" value="go" />
```

The problem starts in page 3 where it should dislpay all names that the user enters in search form in page 1 and the country that selected in page 2.

Page 3 is the following:

```
$value = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['value']);

$name_and_surname = explode(" ", "$value ");
$name = $name_and_surname[0];
$surname = $name_and_surname[1]; 

$sql = " SELECT u.name, 
            u.surname, 
            u.email, 
            u.user_id,
            p.user_id
            FROM users u 
            INNER JOIN profile p ON p.country = '$value'
            WHERE u.surname LIKE '$surname%' AND u.user_id = p.user_id ";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

    while($run = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

        $surname = $run['surname'];
        $name = $run['name'];
    echo"<a href='profile_full.php?email=$email'>  $surname   $name  "; 
    }
```

How can I modify my code in page 3 so that it will get values from page 1 (name that users wants to find) and values from page 2 (countries from which these names are).

Comment: try to use session  and you  can retrive value  on any page you want  just by starting session and calling variable

Comment: Page 3 will only know what went on in page 1 if you either store it in a session, or pass it back on page 2 so that it can send the info back for page 3 again

Comment: any idea how I can do this with session?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you need to make a session or you must also parse the first value in the second page.

First page is OK

2en page in the form must be.

```
<form method="get[value]" name="go" action="location.php"  >        
<select name="country"> 
<option value=" "> select </option> 
<option value="Afganistan">Afghanistan</option>
<option value="Albania">Albania</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="valuep1" value="<?=$value?>">
<input type="submit" value="go" />
```

Your code does have more error.
But if you want to get all information in page 3 you must do in page 3

```
$value = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['valuep1']);
$countryu = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['country']);
```

A name in a form is the name how you can get the value. On page one your value to get it is value. That is confusing you better can call it search. And if you then do $_GET['search'] then you will get the value.

First thing to do is to better understand how a form works and use better names so that you can't confusing yourself. More info here http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Comment: thank you so much for your help...works perfect! you saved me a lot of time

Answer (score 0):

In page2, you can just add:

```
<input type="hidden" name="surname" value="<?=$namevalue?>">
```

Session is way to complicated way of handling such simple usage.

Also, its much better to handle all this in one page with text field and select box with the countries and select from the table based on what you have as entered information.